# Jquery, having trouble with .focus()

Tags: jquery, materialize

I'm working on getting autocomplete library to show suggestion as user types in the search field.

However it isn't working as planned. When .focus() line 6 on .js is uncommented, it focuses to the input field, however it still requires an extra click for the autosuggestion to start working.

It's better described when you look at the code: https://jsfiddle.net/pu7draz2/6/

```
$("#nav-search-button").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$("#nav-main-contents").hide();
$("#nav-search").show(1000);
//$("#channel-search-input").focus(); // <-- uncomment me
});
$('#channel-search-input').focusout(function() {
$("#nav-search").hide();
$("#nav-main-contents").fadeIn(800);
$("#channel-search-input").
```

With commented .focus(), you would have to manually click the search box twice so the auto suggestion would work and this goes the same for when .focus() enabled. But I would like the auto suggestion to start working as the user types.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
$("#nav-search-button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#nav-main-contents").hide();
    $("#nav-search").show(1000, function(){
        $("#channel-search-input").trigger('click').focus();
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code instead of $("#channel-search-input").focus();

```
  $( "#channel-search-input" ).keydown(function() {
  alert( "key down !!!" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Trigger the `click` event of the textbox by using `$("#channel-search-input").click();` after focus as shown below.

```
$("#nav-search-button").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $("#nav-main-contents").hide();
   $("#nav-search").show(1000);
   $("#channel-search-input").focus();
   $("#channel-search-input").click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try onkeyup Event with INPUT. Add code for autosuggestion in onkeyup Event function. You may need some checking (from my old code) like

```
function onkeyupfn(e) {
    var key = window.event ? e.keyCode : e.which;

    if (key == 40 || key == 38) {
        scrolldiv(key);
    }
    else {
        autosuggestion();
    }
}
```